# Looking for a math font where the \mathbb command gives solid (vs hollow) letters

Tags: fonts, math-fonts

Looking for a math font where the \mathbb command gives solid (vs hollow) letters. For example, here is an article that had that kind of solid \mathbb letters. The image shows a \mathbb{P} and a \mathbb{C}.

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: You just want `\mathbf{P}`.    `\mathbb` is "black-board bold" double struck with chalk on a blackboard where real bold is not available. You would not call a solid bold font blackboard bold, it's simply bold.

Comment: If you do want to see the different options for `\mathbb`, check out the documentation for [unicode-math](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/unicode-math/unimath-symbols.pdf) and mathalpha. Both have font specimens.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle That's it! Thanks! Do you think you could make this an answer so I can adopt?

Answer (score 1):

You just want `\mathbf{P}`. `\mathbb` is "black-board bold" double struck with chalk on a blackboard where real bold is not available. You would not call a solid bold font blackboard bold, it's simply bold